# What is a gender-neutral way of saying "middle-man"?

Tags: gender-neutral

As per the title, I'm looking for an alternative phrasing for "middle-man" without the gender connotations.

Comment: Why?  Are you also looking for an alternative phrasing for *woman*?

Comment: "Go-between" has essentially the same meaning.

Comment: @deadrat, no, I'm talking about an intermediary which is an object rather than a person so want to avoid using gender.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  Without knowing the context in which this object operates, it's hard to come up with the right substitute.

Comment: The terms *negotiator* and *mediator* could also work, I guess.

Comment: I don't know how this could have been more clear, I cannot understand the reason for closure. They want an alternate expression without the word `man`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***[Middleperson](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/middleperson):***

> - A middleman or middlewoman.

(Wiktionary)

***[Intermediary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intermediary):***

> - (Law) a person who acts as a mediator or agent between parties

(Collins)

Comment: I think Collins misses a bit by pegging "intermediary" as a legal term.  The Webster's definition at the same link gives "an intermediate agent or agency; a go-between or mediator" without narrowing that definition's scope.  I see it used that way in literature and occasionally in general speech.

Comment: This is only one definition of *middleman*. The other is a distributor of goods, the person who buys from producers or wholesalers and sells to retailers or individuals.

Comment: @deadrat while intermediary isn't perhaps in common use for "node in the distribution chain," it could certainly be used that way.

Comment: @phoog Anything could happen.  A brief time in the google leads me to believe that an intermediary has a relationship between two parties and is generally known by both, even if the parties don't know each other.  There can be several successive middlemen in a commercial chain, and most if not all are generally unknown to those on the ends.  In fact, that's the rap on middlemen -- they're anonymous injectors of superfluous costs

Answer (score 2):

***intermediate***

> A person who acts between others; intermediary; mediator.
>
> [Random House Kennerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intermediate)

Answer (score -2):

For one of the two senses of the term, 'intermediary' seems like a perfectly cromulent word. For the other, someone who is engaged in the business of buying at one place and selling at another, 'reseller' is the best that I can come up with. That word doesn't really capture the historical connotations of 'middleman minorities', for example. I am unsure of what might be an appropriate substitute.